# array include range from python in c++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, slice

I have an array in python, which is declared as follow:

```
u[time][space]
```

My code in Python's for loop requires me to do the following:

```
for n in range(0,10):
    u[n][:] = 1
```

This colon indicates the whole range of my [space].
Now, how would I go about to use the colon (:) to indicate the whole range when doing for loop in c++?

Thanks

Comment: Use 2 loops in C++ instead of one (like in Python).

Comment: You might use something like `auto v = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(time, std::vector<int>(space, 1));` instead.

Comment: this question is pretty vague. what exactly are you trying to do? if you're just trying to assign vectors a value of 1, look at [constructor 4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) -- otherwise, manipulating vectors takes two loops because it doesn't have slicing syntax on lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(auto& inner : u)
    std::fill(inner.begin(), inner.end(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops as suggested.
Something like:

```
int n, s;
for(n=0; n<10; n++){
   for(s=0; s<space; s++){
      u[n][s] = 1;
   }
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have an equivalent to

```
for n in range(0,10):
    u[n][:] = 1
```

You are going to have to write the loop that `u[n][:] = 1` represents.  Fortunately with ranged based for loops it is pretty trivial.  That would look like

```
int foo[3][3];
for (auto& row : foo)
    for (auto& col : row)
        col = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember a quick way to do it in C++. I'm afraid you'd have to loop in each table.

This would look like this (admitting that `space` is a known integer):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < space; j++)
        u[i][j] = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to use two loops. Modern C++ has some tricks up its sleeve to make initializing these loops simple, but here is a basic C example that will work anywhere:

```
#define TIME_MAX 100
#define SPACE_MAX 350

int u[TIME_MAX][SPACE_MAX];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < TIME_MAX; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SPACE_MAX; j++)
        u[i][j] = 1;
```